# Windows 7 claims driver is not digitally signed, but it is

Tags: windows-7, drivers, digital-signature

On this system the WLAN AutoConfig service will not start:

In error log/system:

"The WLAN AutoConfig service depends on the NativeWiFi Filter service
which failed to start because of the following error:
Windows cannot verify the digital signature for this file. A recent
hardware or software change might have installed a file that is signed
incorrectly or damaged, or that might be malicious software from an
unknown source."

In error/log security:

"Code integrity determined that the image hash of a file is not
valid. The file could be corrupt due to unauthorized modification or
the invalid hash could indicate a potential disk device error.
C:\Windows\system32\drivers\nwifi.sys"

I ran sfc /scannow and it found no errors.

[I ran sigverif and it says that this file, along with vwififlt.sys are not signed.](http://pastebin.com/JEu6LtCV)

Next I uploaded [nwifi.sys](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/54c2e77bce1037711a11313ac25b8706109098c10a31aa03aeb7a185e97800d7/analysis/1365072696/) and [vwififlt.sys](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/30f6ba594b0d3b94113064015a16d97811cd989df1715cce21ceab9894c1b4fb/analysis/1365074492/) to virustotal, which says they are signed and Ok.

Finally I directly compared these files with the same files on another Windows 7 machine. They have identical sha256 and md5 sums, and the other machine thinks that they are signed.

What is happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Windows drivers often do not contain the digital signature within the actual file. Instead, all the signatures for a group of drivers are bundled into a single file called a catalog. If this file becomes damaged, all the files which it authenticates will be marked as unsigned. Windows will not tell you that it is really the catalog that is damaged, you just have to guess. It also won't tell you which catalog is damaged. The catalogs are stored in `c:\windows\system32\catroot\`.

You have to go to a working machine and run sigverif and then look at the log. You'll see a line like this for the file:

`nwifi.sys                14/07/2009     2:5.1,2:5.2,2:6.0,2:Signed              Microsoft-Windows-ClMicrosoft Windows`

`Microsoft-Windows-Cl` is part of the name of the catalog containing this file's signature. Windows doesn't bother to tell us the whole file name and there are 11 catalog files which begin with this string. In order to find which one it really is you must install the Windows SDK to get the program `signtool.exe`. In the catroot folder, under a long CLSID, you will find a bunch of files which begin with this string. In order to figure out which one is damaged, use signtool to try to verify nwifi.sys. Eventually you'll find it:

`signtool verify /a /c c:\windows\system32\catroot\{F...}\Windows-Client-Features-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.7601.17514.cat c:\windows\system32\drivers\nwifi.sys`

This command will succeed on a normal Windows 7 machine (with wifi). On the problem machine it fails. After comparing the catalog files I found they were different, and indeed Windows would refuse to open the damaged one if I double clicked it directly. Of course it would offer no clue at all what the problem was until I already figured it out.

So at this point to fix the machine you simply copy the catalog from the working machine to the broken one.

Comment: Actually the information here is somewhat wrong, because it discusses two different types of signatures. One is the signature created by the vendor who authored the driver; the one on the catalog file, however, is the counter-signature from Microsoft. It may stem from simple attestation signing or even from the vendor going through all the hoops of sysdev/HLK testing. So a driver file may be signed by the vendor only or by the vendor *and* counter-signed by Microsoft through attestation or logo-signing. The latter is checked by asking `signtool.exe` to use the kernel signing policy!